# Is it possible to throw an alert recover in a datadog log alert monitor set with terraform

Tags: terraform, alert, monitor, datadog

I have a question regarding creating a monitor for a log alert.

I’m doing a monitor for a log alert with terraform (resource `datadog_monitor`). The idea is to create an alert if more than 10 logs with the same `userId` inside their context appear in the last 15 minutes and recover the alert if there isn’t any log in the last 15 minutes. The terraform config is the following:

```
resource "datadog_monitor" "default" {
  count   = 1
  name    = "Monitor Name"
  type    = "log alert"
  message = "Check alert"

  query = "logs(\"Hello\").index(\"*\").rollup(\"count\").by(\"@context.userId\").last(\"15m\") >= 10"

  monitor_thresholds {
    critical          = 10
    critical_recovery = 1
  }

  escalation_message   = "Check alert - No data"
  on_missing_data      = "default"
  timeout_h            = 0
  renotify_interval    = 120
  renotify_occurrences = 0
  renotify_statuses = [
    "alert",
    "warn",
  ]

  new_group_delay     = "60"
  require_full_window = false
  enable_logs_sample  = true
}
```

Everything is working fine except the alert recovery. When there is no data, the query result is the last result with data, which is bigger or equal than 1. Therefore, it is not possible to see the recovery. Do you know what is happening? As far as I’ve seen in the documentation, if `on_missing_data` is set to `default`, the query should throw a 0 on missing data on a query of type count.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Without seeing fully reproducible blocks of code, it is very hard to tell.

Comment: You are right, the question has been edited. I hope now is it better to understand!

Comment: Checking the documentation (https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/types/log/), I found the following: `When splitting the monitor by any dimension (tag or facet) and using a below condition, the alert is triggered if and only if there are logs for a given group, and the count is below the threshold—or if there are no logs for all of the groups.`. It seems it is not possible to get the recovery alert if we are using a group by. But do you know some different way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried setting `on_missing_data` to `"show_and_notify_no_data"`?